# Trouble with the pen tool

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I am having trouble with the pen tool. It was working just fine until it didn't want to fill the path. I don't know what I did to have this kind of problem. I'm currently using Photoshop CS6 and I mostly use the pen and brush tool for the illustrations. After I created the path, I right click and try to fill the path. It didn't do anything. I try to find the "add to path" effect, but I couldn't find it. Please, I need help.

Answer (score 1):

A few things to make sure...

Make sure your [pen settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j7S68.png) are set properly. Note that the left most box creates a shape as you use the pen tool whereas the second box only creates the path that you wll need to fill manually.

Also make sure you are working on a layer, *not* a layer mask.

Finally, ensure that the color you are filling the path with isn't identical with the background color, else it might be hard to see.